# Is it possible that jChartFX will automaticlly position my text annotation on the chart based on (X, series)?

Tags: javascript, jchartfx

I am using an line chart with text annotation.
According to the documentation of jChartFX, in order to put an annotation, I have to do something like `annText3.attachElastic(2.9, 3200, 6.2, 2800);` (based on [that](http://www.jchartfx.com/demo/85ad0570-8b8d-e211-84a5-0019b9e6b500) example) and provide bounds for entire text cube.
Is it possible to give only x value, and draw an arrow with its end exactly on the line series, and the text and a reasonable location?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging in jChartFX docs i found out that it is not possbile